# How can i manipulate csv's from within c++

Tags: c++, excel, csv

I am trying to create a program that can read out to a csv (comma separated). Is there a way to manipulate say the column width or whether a cell is left or right justified internally from my code so that when i open up the file in excel it looks better than a bunch of strings cramped into tiny cells. My goal is for the user to do as little thinking as possible. If they open up the file and have to size everything right just to see it that seems a little crummy.

Comment: A *.csv file doesn't have any information at all about graphical cell width. That's entirely up to Excel.

Comment: `cvs` is a very simple ASCII file. No width, justify, or whatever other info than plain data.

Comment: So your saying that, what? The only thing a csv is good for is data organization? That stinks, but i guess that is how it is.

Comment: So does excel offer another file format? One that can be manipulated as suggested - that's the better question

Comment: Excel may also support XML.  You'll have to research that one.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews XLSX uses a particular XML schema. XML itself isn't a file format but can be used to describe one.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is a plain text file format. It doesn't support any visual formatting. For that, you need to write the data to another file format such as `.xlsx` or `.ods`.